# changing the lock screen time and date display lg l5

Tags: lock-screens, customization, clock

How do i change the design and look of the time and date display on my lock screen?  Where is the option that lets you change the design/way the time and date is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize these `clock and date styles` only if the `screen lock` is `Swipe`.

Even you can choose between `Analog` and `Digital` clocks and much more.

If `screen lock` option is `Pattern`/`Password`, this `clock/date styles` can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can't have your screen lock security as a pattern. It can only be swiped to change the clock.